# Adding Items to an Empty Array with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I'm just learning Javascript and need to build a cart.
I am using a drop-down menu to select the items which are stored in another array. I then want to push the selected item to an empty array called "cart"

This is the code I'm using to select the data from the catalog array inorder to push it to the cart array:

```
let addFCat = document.getElementById('addfromCat');

function cat_Cart(){ 

  // find out the index of the item loaded
  let e = document.getElementById("productList");
  let itemIndex = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  console.log(itemIndex);

  // update item to cart
  cart.push(catalog[itemIndex]);
  localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));

  // alert with updated total
  // alert(`You added ${cartItems.name} to your Cart`)

}
```

But for some reason my cart[] remains empty.

If I manually type:
cart.push(catalog[*enter index here*]) in the console,
and then:
cart.length;
the cart updates.
What am I doing wrong, that it won't update my cart within the function?

(PS. I'm using the console.logs to check the code is running)

Comment: I assume you're calling the `cat_Cart` function. How are you logging/checking the contents of `cart` after you push to it?

Comment: Where is the array declared? And did you use "var" or "let"?

Comment: You may add `console.log(catalog[itemIndex])` to print the content of `catalog[itemIndex]` for debugging.

Comment: Also, when you say your array is empty, does it look like `[]` or does it contain something like `[undefined]` or `[null]`?

Comment: Apologies, 
I had previously had console.log(catalog[itemIndex]) to double-check it was accessing the correct item from the array. It was correctly identifying the item.
@NickParsons I was using the console to check the contents of the cart. 
It returned [], not null or undefined, but no items inside.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is because you do refresh your browser, and it causes your cart[] to be empty, I suggest you to store the cart array in empty condition, to localStorage first, and get the updated value like this

```js
const cart = []

localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));

function cat_Cart(){ 

  const getCart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));

  // find out the index of the item loaded
  let e = document.getElementById("productList");
  let itemIndex = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  console.log(itemIndex);

  // update item to cart
  getCart.push(catalog[itemIndex]);
  localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(getCart));

  // alert with updated total
  // alert(`You added ${cartItems.name} to your Cart`)

}
```

local storage will help you to save any data, and it will not to be deleted even though you refresh the browser. thank you